# how should i be binding spacebar to serve my purpose?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to figure how to set up pause and unpause function on my game that allows me to use space to pause and then unpause as well. I've been struggling mostly because I'm so new to coding. I feel like I'm not understanding the true and false or rather the binds.
The code is as follows:

```
import random
from tkinter import *

def paused(window):

    PAUSED = False

    while True:
        pause(window)
        canvas.create_text(canvas.winfo_width() / 2, canvas.winfo_height() / 2, font=('consolas', 70), text="PAUSED", fill="white", tag='paused')
        window.keys.bind("<space>", paused)
        if not paused:
            paused = False
            window.update()
```

Comment: You'll have to tell us how `window` was created. With Tkinter ? PyGame ? pandas ? Gtk ?

Comment: i am using tkinter

Comment: Okay. then you need to show us the part of the code where this function gets called from. Else I cannot know what that event is.

Comment: i have edited the question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using `pygame`. In pygame, you can listen to `pygame.event` and check if the space bar has been clicked.

```
PAUSED = False

while True: 
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE: 
                 PAUSED = not PAUSED # inverts PAUSED
    if not PAUSED: 
        draw() # update
    clock.tick(60)
```

Otherwise, you can use the `keyboard` module.